# django, reactjs, ngnix: deploy prosses

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have few question about django rest development. I'm building project with DRF, wsgi, ngnix on the backend side, and reactjs on front.

**Questions**:
1) bloking endpoints for user and other services beside of react frontend:
we have such situation: now evry each person can get data from endpoint if he or she write correct url adress. How can I stop it. So the goal is that now one can see it, only `react`

2) how to setup ngnix that ngnix is gona serve fronted add in react, regardles where django api is?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can't protect it, it's just a matter of making it slightly more difficult for an average Joe. Some options to explore: use [CSRF token](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/csrf/), check [Referer HTTP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer), make it available only for authenticated users (registration with email, captcha, credit card, etc), throttling and blacklist by IP (+browser fingerprint), sky is the limit.
2. Are you asking how to move your react sources out of django's `/static/` folder? You can just map your frontend folder in nginx directly, so you won't be using `collectstatic` to deploy anymore and can simply link frontend url in your templates directly `<script src='/frontend/react.js'></script>` (you can load it from another server if you want).

   ```
   server {
       listen      80;

       # where django static files are, like for admin app
       location /static {
           alias /var/www/static;
       }

       # where your frontend js files are
       location /frontend {
           alias /home/user/frontend;
       }

       # regular uwsgi 
       location / {
           uwsgi_pass  unix:/home/user/app.sock;
           include     uwsgi_params;
       }

   }
   ```